# pasar texto a input segun value de select

Tags: php, laravel-blade, livewire

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto laravel 8 y livewire donde necesito insertar un valor dinamico a un input segun el valor que seleccione en el select, estuve probando con el metodo updatedFoo ejemplo de livewire pero no logre que me funcione.

este es mi select

```
<label class="form-label required" for="id_deliveryway">{{ trans('cruds.order.fields.id_deliveryway') }}</label>
<x-select-list class="mt-1 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 block w-full shadow-sm sm:text-sm border-gray-300 rounded-md" required id="id_deliveryway" name="id_deliveryway" :options="$this->listsForFields['id_deliveryway']" wire:model="order.id_deliveryway_id"  wire:change="change"/>
  <div class="validation-message">
    {{ $errors->first('order.id_deliveryway_id') }}
  </div>
  <div class="help-block">
    {{ trans('cruds.order.fields.id_deliveryway_helper') }}
  </div>
```

y aqui es donde busco insertar un texto dinamico

```
<div class="col-span-3 sm:col-span-3">
  <label class="form-label required" for="address">Forma de envio</label>
  <input class="mt-1 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 block w-full shadow-sm sm:text-sm border-gray-300 rounded-md" type="text" name="pickupdelivery" id="pickupdelivery" required wire:model="pickupdelivery">
  <div class="validation-message">
    {{ $errors->first('order.address') }}
  </div>
  <div class="help-block">
    {{ trans('cruds.order.fields.address_helper') }}
  </div>
</div>
```

He probado con una funcion asi pero nada

```
public function change()
    {
        dd("Here");
    }
```

probe con updatedFoo, es decir

```
public function updatedId_deliveryway_id()
{
  $this->pickupdelivery = "Cualquier texto a insertar";
}
```

Pero tampoco funciono, les pido un poco de ayuda con mi codigo para solucionar mi problema por favor. Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno lo he solucionado utilizando el metodo updatedFoo(ejemplo de livewire) es decir un lifecycle hooks, lo que hice fue en mi vista cambiar el valor de `wire:model="order.id_deliveryway_id"` a solo `wire:model="id_deliveryway"` la declare como propiedad publica `public $id_deliveryway;` y luego realice esta funcion

```
public function updatedIdDeliveryway($id_deliveryway)
{       
  $formaenviotext = DeliveryMethod::select('address', 'id')->where('id', 
  $id_deliveryway)->first();
  //dd($formaenviotext);
  $this->pickupdelivery = $formaenviotext->address;
}
```

Es decir, recibe el id_deliveryway del select y cuando este es actualizado, es decir cambia de un valor a otro luego ejecuta la consulta al modelo DeliveryMethod para traer el address que se inserta en el input text.

Les dejo la solucion por si alguien tiene la misma necesidad o problema a futuro...

Answer (score 0):

Creo que podrías trabajar mejor con JavaScript, te adjunto un ejemplo espero te pueda servir.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <script>
       a = 0;
     function addinput(){
       var valorSelect = document.getElementById("myselect").value;
        a++;
       var div = document.createElement('div');
       div.setAttribute('class', 'form-inline');
       div.innerHTML = '<div style="clear:both"><input value="'+valorSelect+'" name="input_'+a+'" type="text"/></div>';
       document.getElementById('inputdinamico').appendChild(div);document.getElementById('inputdinamico').appendChild(div);
      }
   </script>
  </head>
  <body>
     <select id="myselect" onchange="addinput()" >
     <option value="opcion 1">opción1</option>
     <option value="opcion 2">opción2</option>
     <option value="opcion 3">opción3</option>
     <option value="opcion 4">opción4</option>
     <option value="opcion 5">opción5</option>
     </select>
     <div class="container">    
       <div class="row" id="inputdinamico"></div>
     </div>
  </body>
</html>
```